# Test that RxJava BehaviorProcessor emits a value

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4, rx-java2

I'm having trouble understanding why all those processors pass the test but `Behavior` does not:

```
package com.example;

import org.junit.Test;

import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import io.reactivex.processors.*;

public class ProcessorTest {
    private static Flowable<String> justFoo() {
        return Flowable.just("foo");
    }

    private static FlowableProcessor<String> subscribeToFoo(
            FlowableProcessor<String> processor) {
        justFoo().subscribe(processor);
        return processor;
    }

    @Test public void flowable() {  // pass
        justFoo().test().assertValue("foo");
    }

    @Test public void async() {  // pass
        subscribeToFoo(AsyncProcessor.create()).test().assertValue("foo");
    }

    @Test public void replay() {  // pass
        subscribeToFoo(ReplayProcessor.create()).test().assertValue("foo");
    }

    @Test public void unicast() {  // pass
        subscribeToFoo(UnicastProcessor.create()).test().assertValue("foo");
    }

    @Test public void behaviorFail() {  // fail
        subscribeToFoo(BehaviorProcessor.create()).test().assertValue("foo");
    }

    @Test public void behaviorPassing() {  // pass
        subscribeToFoo(BehaviorProcessor.create())
                .test()
                .assertNoValues()
                .assertSubscribed()
                .assertComplete()
                .assertNoErrors()
                .assertNoTimeout()
                .assertTerminated();
    }
}
```

The docs say that `BehaviorProcessor` is a:

> Processor that emits the most recent item it has observed and all subsequent observed items to each subscribed Subscriber.

So in my understanding it should pass the `behaviorFail` test, not the `behaviorPassing`. How come is that?

How would I write a valid test, to know that a `BehaviorProcessor` emitted a certain value?

Comment: When a `BehaviorProcessor` is terminated, the cached value is no longer available to late `Subscriber`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting rid of the terminal event passed to the processor would help:

```
@Test public void behavior() {
    final BehaviorProcessor<String> processor = BehaviorProcessor.create();
    justFoo().concatWith(Flowable.never()).subscribe(processor);
    processor.test().assertValue("foo");
}
```